# Filter for ListBinding doesn' work correctly

Tags: javascript, sapui5

in my SAPUI5-App, I have a GeoMap (sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap) with some Spots (sap.ui.vbm.Spots) displayed. Each Spot has a quarter assigned (for example 2012-Q3, 2012-Q4, ...). Above this GeoMap, I have a RangeSlider (sap.ui.commons.RangeSlider) where I can select a range of quarters (for example from 2012-Q4 to 2014-Q3). Depending on the selected quarters in the RangeSlider, only the associated Spots should be displayed on the GeoMap. 
[Image of my Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jok1c.jpg)

I already implemented this so far and if I reduce the range in my RangeSlider, the correct Spots will be displayed on the GeoMap.

BUT, and this is my Problem, if I extend the range in my RangeSlider, not all relevant Spots will be shown on the GeoMap. Some Spots are missing.
[Image: Not all Spots will be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeCuo.jpg)

My read is, there must something wrong with my filter.

This is the Code from my Event-Handler for the RangeSlider:

```
onRangeChanged: function(oEvent){
        var oValue1 = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
        var oValue2 = oEvent.getSource().getValue2();
        var aFilter = [];
        for (var i = oValue1; i <= oValue2; i++) {
            var sQuarter = oEvent.getSource().mProperties.labels[i];
            aFilter.push(new Filter("EVENT_QUARTAL", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuarter));
        }
        var combinedFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(aFilter, false);
        var oSpots = this.getView().byId("SpotsEvent");
        var oListBinding = oSpots.getBinding("items");
        oListBinding.filter(combinedFilter);
    },
```

And here is a code snippet form my View with the Spots and the RangeSlider:

```
...
<commons:RangeSlider 
            id="RangeSlider"
            min="0"
            max="15"
            stepLabels="true"
            smallStepWidth="1"
            width="1070px" 
            value="0"
            value2="15"
            change="onRangeChanged"
            class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin">
</commons:RangeSlider>
...
<vbm:Spots
        id="SpotsEvent"
        items="{/Events/0}">
            <vbm:items>
                <vbm:Spot
                    id="spotEvent"
                    click="onClickSpot"
                    position="{path: 'EVENT_GEOKOORDINATEN',
                               formatter: '.Formatter.formatPosition'}"
                    type="Error"
                    text="{BRANDSCORE}">
                </vbm:Spot>
            </vbm:items>
        </vbm:Spots>
```

I hope somebody can help me.